# PHP checkbox values to MYSQL infinity loop problem

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make settings to a profile on my website with checkboxes. The checkboxes work too, but I keep getting this error: `Fatal error : Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Column 'match_role_id' cannot be null`

It's probably because the table in which the values should be entered is a temporary table with two IDs from two other tables.
If I set the default value of the two values to **NULL** I have an infinity loop.

[image: Table structure]

How can I fix this?

Function:

```
function add_team_match_role() {

    global $connection;

    if(isset($_POST['add_match_roles'])) {

        $match_role_checkbox = $_POST['match_role_check'];
        $team_id = escape($_POST['team_id']);

        for($i = 0; $i < $match_role_checkbox; $i++) {

            $team_id = escape($_POST['team_id']);

            $stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO game_role_team (match_role_id, team_id) VALUES (?, ?)");
            $stmt->bind_param("ss", $match_role_checkbox[$i], $team_id);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();

        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="match_role">Match Rollen</label>
        
    <?php 
        $stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM game_role");
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            $match_role_id = $row['match_role_id'];
            $match_role_name = $row['match_role_name'];

            echo "<div class='form-check'>
                  <input class='form-check-input' type='checkbox' name='match_role_check[]' value='$match_role_id'>
                  <label class='form-check-label'>$match_role_name</label>
                  </div>";

        }

        $stmt->close();
    ?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a checkbox is not set, then `$_POST['add_match_roles'][$i]` is NULL. But you are not allowed to insert NULL or empty string, because the field is integer.

Check if the role is checked by verifying 'set and not empty' (because the value is 'on'). If empty, give a zero or a one when checked.

```
$isChecked = (int) !empty($_POST['add_match_roles'][$i]);
```

Also correct the type from string to integer

```
$stmt->bind_param("is", $isChecked, $team_id);
```

> **Note**:
> Use TinyInt(1) UNSIGNED if you just need a boolean value (true=1, false=0).